# How do i traverse through an xml document that has identical elements?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-xml

i have the following xml file

```
<Universe id="123nebula" name="winterfell"  parentId="0">
  <planet id="gio234" name="bobka grantos">
    <planet id="tyu88" name="viola winter" description="dgdgdddgddgdddgd"/>
  </planet>
  <planet id="huio90" name="bintor nardi" description="dedededddddddddd"/>
  <planet id="ruil99" name="torian fartknox" description="llllklklklkkllk"/>
  <planet id="huy7777" name="vivalid durol" description="ppppppppppssssss"/>
  <planet id="fila7866" name="hella fella dorrrah">
    <planet id="asaaa23" name="Sixty two nine pine" description="ffffffffdfdfd"/>
    <planet id="tyu88" name="viola winter" description="dgdgdddgddgdddgd"/>
    <planet id="juiiko8" name="tae bo" description="jujujioooppoiiu"/>
  </planet>
</Universe>
```

In here some planets are by them selves and some planets have sub planets. Since all parent planets and sub planets have the same element name 'planet' the only way to identify the parent planet is by looking for *description* `attribute` where only the child (sub) planets have the "*description*" `attribute`.

i want to do two things:

1. I need to get all sub planet of the parent planets whos `id = fila7866`
2. i want to get all the planets that don't have child planets

**Update**
this needs to be done using LINQ-2-XML!

How do i do this?

Comment: Don't like to look too old-fashioned, but nonetheless - what have you actually tried before posting? There are a lot of info over the net about how to use X(ml)Document, and I am sure that even for traversing such trees there are at least few hits. If you have an actual problem then provide some code that can [demonstrate it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @EugenePodskal it should be done using LINQ-2-XML and i updated my post with it

Comment: I am still quite assured that you should have tried to solve this on your own. But that's your own business...

Comment: @EugenePodskal i know how to get elements if they have a variety and a certain xpath pattern but in this case all elements have the same name except the root element. this something unique i believe

Comment: But have you made an attempt to use certain xpath assuming that such elements are not something unique? I can assure you that with fully qualified xpath there is no difference how nodes are named. They can all have the same name - it won't actually matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Deserialize single instance
        XmlSerializer serializerSingle = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Universe));//, new XmlRootAttribute("document"));
        using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(@"<Path to your XML data>\planet.xml"))
        {
            // 'ReadXML.Xml2CSharp.Document' is the 'Document' class in your XML Classes
            Universe dezerializedXMLSingle = (Universe)serializerSingle.Deserialize(stream);

            var SubPlanets = (from p in dezerializedXMLSingle.Planet where p.Id == "fila7866" select p.Planets).ToList();

        } // Put a break-point here, then mouse-over dezerializedXMLSingle
    }
}
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="planet")]
public class Planet {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="planet")]
    public List<Planet> Planets { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Universe")]
public class Universe {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="planet")]
    public List<Planet> Planet { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="parentId")]
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

I stored your XML in a file and De-serialize to an object called dezerializedXMLSingle... quite cool actually because if you put a break-point in the code just after the  dezerializedXMLSingle line, then mouse-over and examine the data structure of 'dezerializedXMLSingle' object, you'll see each  planet and then the Planets associated with those planets, in the case of fila7866 you will see 3 [sub] Planets.... Hope that helps....

Comment: Two nitpickings: 1. It doesn't actually filter the required information from the deserialized structure. 2. It doesn't use [LINQ-to-XML](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/linq/564/linq-to-xml-tutorials-examples) as required by the OP.

Comment: @EugenePodskal it was good reply by monty, he created an object haiving those properties but Eugene was correct it does not answer the two questions in my OP so i cannot give marks

Comment: @Monty i wanted to use LINQ-to-XML it was my bad i did not mentioned it in my OP

Comment: @Eugene Podskal. The OP has not provided any code, they have only tag the question with LNQ-to-XML, among other things. It was not specifically requested and they probably do not visualise a solution in anything in particular. Also, the OP can do the rest using LINQ to extract the the required information from the dezerializedXMLSingle object, a simple one-liner. If I do all the work then the OP will never learn anything for themselves....

Comment: @Monty No offense, but if you care about "the OP will never learn anything for themselves" then you probably shouldn't have given [this answer at all](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems). And now it is 1. answer to not the most high-quality post 2. answer that doesn't fully answer the question. P.S.: It would have taken not much longer to just rework your answer to use Linq-to-XML than it took to write your previous comment :).

Comment: @Monty i have updated my OP : )

Comment: @EugenePodskal excuse me for a second, you mentioned in our comment to Monty "Answer to not the most high-quality post". well Eugene high quality post are posted typically by experts and not everyone here is an expert and whole idea of a forum is to help each other and i have gone through SO guidelines and by reading them gives me the impression SO expects the author of posts to be mid-level to expert developer whats going to happen to beginners and in-betweens?

Comment: @Eugene Podskal. LOL. Then why don't you.... you free to answer the question yourself but chose to criticise others instead... knock yourself out...

Comment: @blatheringbob You haven't tried anything to solve the problem on your own. Well, you may have tried, but there is nothing in the post indicating that. And high quality has nothing to do with being an expert - but it has to do a lot with [determination and attention to details](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). That's a pity that you don't want to try to solve this problem by yourself. You may consider me and other like me as a**holes, but we just want to have educated colleagues who can code and have a place where we can ask a question that

Comment: @blatheringbob will get answered and won't be lost in the mire of give-me-the-codez

Comment: @blatheringbob WOW Eh...  I see you only joined SO today AND your first question, don't be put off... it can be like the first day at primary school.... LOL

Comment: okay mates, i dont want to $krew first day in the club

Comment: @blathering bob. I'm cool, have updated my answer with an example to retrieve the data you needed... you'll also need to add this..... 'using System.Linq;'

Comment: @blatheringbob - Just quick comment on your reply to Eugene - the Stack Overflow site works by having a frank and honest community that helps to lift the quality of everyone's questions and answers. The only way to learn to provide better content is to have previous content appraised - that's what the up-voting, accepting, and commenting is all about. It's everyone's chance to learn so that they improve.